# How to append to HTML5 localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I do a

```
localStorage.setItem('oldData', $i("textbox").value);
```

to set the value of key `oldData` to the value in a textbox.

The next time something is entered to the textbox, I want to append to the already existing `oldData`.

So, if I enter **apples** and then **oranges** in my textbox, my localStorage key `oldData` should look like this:

Initially:

```
Key      |   Value
---------------------------
oldData  |  apples
```

Now:

```
oldData  |  apples oranges
```

How can I append? **Is there an `append` method provided?**

Or do I need to read the data first, append in javascript and then write back?

Comment: You can retrieve the curent value of the key and then add the new value...

Comment: @Cristy: So there is no append provided with localStorage API?

Comment: I don't know, never used it, but this could work until someone posts an "append" method :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no `append` function. It's not hard to write one though:

```
function appendToStorage(name, data){
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if(old === null) old = "";
    localStorage.setItem(name, old + data);
}

appendToStorage('oldData', $i("textbox").value);
```

Note: It makes more sense to define a function `append` on the `localStorage` object. **However**, because `localStorage` has a `setter`, this is not possible. If you were trying to define a function using `localStorage.append = ...`, the `localStorage` object will interpret this attempt as *"Save an object called `append` in the Storage object"*.

Comment: I think I have spotted an error here, I am not sure what the OP was wanting to write to the localStorage, but since you need to use JSON syntax, make sure you are **properly seperating** your objects, arrays, etc. `localStorage.setItem(name, old + data);` with a simple `+` concatenation might trick you.

Comment: @KovácsImre `localStorage` only stores strings, which is exactly what the OP wanted, so `localStorage.setItem(name, old + data);` is correct. If you want to store non-strings, then you need a custom (de)serialization method. JSON syntax is a convenient way to implement this, but by no means required.

Comment: In that case, it's true.

Comment: @RobW I have saved it.

Comment: can you explain why they call it html5 storage ? this isn't  a feature of browsers?

Answer (score 12):

It is not a good solution but it works and is performative.

```
localStorage.setItem("fruit", "Apples"); 

localStorage.setItem("fruit", localStorage.getItem("fruit") + "Orange");
```

Comment: Sorry. Had understood that he wanted no matter which way information storage (html date localStorage, javascript variable etc.). So the suggestion of html date, since it is recommended to the method for better performance compared to javascript variable.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) :

```
interface Storage {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  DOMString? key(unsigned long index);
  getter DOMString getItem(DOMString key);
  setter creator void setItem(DOMString key, DOMString value);
  deleter void removeItem(DOMString key);
  void clear();
};
```

Seems like it only has getItem,setItem,removeItem,clear,key and length.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could do this by assigning index numbers to the key name.
If you had a HUGE string of data to save, you could save yourself reading and writing the entire string history to the storage and just advance the index name number with the new data. Something like this.

```
function AppendToLocalStorageV(name, value) {
    let n = 0;
    while (localStorage.getItem(name + n)) {
        n++;
    }
    localStorage.setItem(name + n, value); //add item at first available index number
}
```

This would add the first available index number to the end of the key value, thereby creating a new entry. I would also keep track of the current index number to avoid reading all of the entries, or get the localStorage.length variable.
The table would look like this

[image]

Then you could retrieve the key array like so.

```
function GetLocalStorageV(name) {
    let n = 0;
    let data = [];
    while (localStorage.getItem(name + n)) {
        data.push(localStorage.getItem(name + n++));
    }
    return data;
}
```

I added V to the end of the functions to distinguish that we are building vertical arrays in the storage grid.

Now we can simply do this to append and recall the data by it's name.

```
AppendToLocalStorageV("oldData", "apples");    
AppendToLocalStorageV("oldData", "oranges");
AppendToLocalStorageV("oldData", "bananas");
var oldData = GetLocalStorageV("oldData");  //returns an array with [apples,oranges,bananas]
```

You could then access your data just like an array. Get and set values at certain indexes, pop from the end of the array etc. Keep in mind, this creates a new entry every time you append. Rebuilding the index numbers could get expensive if you had to reorder the list as well. Also, I don't know how many keys you can safely generate before you slow down the browser or hit a [max_keys] limit.
But at least you don't have to constantly read and write the entire list of a HUGE string of data every time as it's only writing the new data. I've never tested this with any large amounts of entries, so I'd be careful with this approach.