# Append new data in object array on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, html-framework-7

There is a list of news article in a page. Everytime user clicks on it, it saves news id and title to localstorage. My code is replacing localstorage data everytime I click new item.

How do I append new data into localStorage ?

Setting localStorage

```
awardForArticleRead: function(latestNews){
    var articleData = {};
    articleData['newsId'] = latestNews.news_id;
    articleData['newsTitle'] = latestNews.title;
    localStorage.setItem("articleRead",  JSON.stringify(articleData));
},
```

calling function while it goes to detail page

```
    newsDetail: function(key, id) {
    var _this=this;

    newsDetail = API_DATA['getLatestNews'][key];

    myApp.mainView.loadPage('news1.html');
    myApp.onPageInit("news_detail", function(page){
        _this.awardForArticleRead(newsDetail);
        _this.showNewsDetails(newsDetail);
    })       

},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append to HTML5 localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679955/how-to-append-to-html5-localstorage)

Comment: I think your problem is that the localStorage key you are setting is hardcoded, so every time you call the `awardForArticleRead` method, it overwrites the previous value. Is that what you meant when you said your code is replacing localStorage data?

Comment: yes @djfdev Why I can't keep the same name and different value ?

Comment: you can @Santosh - you just need to read the old value, add the new value, write the amended value - however, you'll need to also change how you store the data - perhaps an array? (which you would still convert to/from JSON of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the old data, convert to object (JSON.parse), add the new data, then write the amended data to localStorage

```
awardForArticleRead: function(latestNews){
    var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("articleRead") || '[]');
    store.push({
        newsId: latestNews.news_id,
        newsTitle: latestNews.title
    });
    localStorage.setItem("articleRead",  JSON.stringify(store));
},
```

this would result in an array of items, like:

```
[{
    newsId: 1,
    newsTitle: 'title 1'
}, {
    newsId: 2,
    newsTitle: 'title 2'
}, {
    newsId: 3,
    newsTitle: 'title 3'
}]
```

so other code that reads the localStorage would have to be changed appropriately

Alternatively:

```
awardForArticleRead: function(latestNews){
    var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("articleRead") || '{}');
    store[latestNews.news_id] = latestNews.title;
    localStorage.setItem("articleRead",  JSON.stringify(store));
}
```

would result in the data being:

```
{ 
    1: 'title1',
    2: 'title2',
    3: 'title3',
}
```

where 1,2,3 are the news_id's

As you have not shown how the localStorage data is used (read) then I can't really say which is the better option for you

Comment: your first solution says `store.push is not defined` but second one work perfectly.

Comment: the first method will fail because your current localStorage is **not** an Array - you'd need to somehow account for the fact that the type of data has changed - if you clear out localStorage (or at least that key) then you'll see the code works just fine

Comment: the second works fine, but the data in localStorage won't be exactly right until you clear it first - as I said, any existing data using a different "format" is not accounted for in the code above

Answer (score 1):

There is no set add or append function, however you can simply gather the old data, combine them in the code and replace the new data into local storage.

Something like this:

```
function addToLocalStorage(nameOfItem, newData){
    var oldData = localStorage.getItem(nameOfItem);
    if(oldData !== null) {
        localStorage.setItem(nameOfItem, oldData + newData);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(nameOfItem, newData);
    }
}
```